# Lifecycle problem when use FragmentStatePagerAdapter, Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onsaveinstancestate

I'm using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, ViewPager.
I'm going to use **onSaveInstanceState** by overriding to save some states like cursor position of EditText in every fragment.
But **when I choose first fragment and next choose second fragment**, the **onSaveInstanceState** of first fragment is not called. If I choose first and next choose third fragment, then the onSaveInstanceState of the first fragment is called.
**In this case of choosing first fragment and next second fragment, even the onPause of the first fragment is not called.**
What's the reason? How can I solve this problem? I have researched about this problem whole day. But I haven't found solution and correct reason yet.
onSaveInstanceState has cases that it can be called, but how about onPause? Why doens't onPause be called?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I used **setUserVisibleHint**.
In fragment, I wrote save and restore logic in **setUserVisibleHint**.
It works well.
This is called when fragment is shown or hidden.
Also I used **onViewStateRestored**, **onSaveInstanceState** together for being destroyed cases.

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            if (mInputFrom != null) {
                if(isToFocus) {
                    mInputFrom.requestFocus();
                    mInputFrom.setSelection(fromCursor);
                } else {
                    mInputOut.requestFocus();
                    mInputOut.setSelection(toCursor);
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (mInputFrom != null) {
                fromCursor = mInputFrom.getSelectionStart();
                toCursor = mInputOut.getSelectionStart();
            }
        }
    }
```

**setUservisibleHint** was deprecated.
So other option is that we can use constructor of **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**(fm, **BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT**);
If we call super's constructor like above in constructor of our customized Adapter that extends **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**, then **onPause**, **onResume** of fragment will be called for every case of being hidden or shown.
First option is suitable for my case I think. So I used first option and has solved perfectly.